# Not able to find source files for itunes-0.4 java lib

Tags: java, rome

above is extension to rome library( to parse RSS/atom feeds) for parsing itunes extensions.
Can some one tell me where I can find source for that. Jar is available at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/i/Downloaditunes04jar.htm.

Any help here would be great. Goggling did not help me much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rometools](https://github.com/rometools/) at github is the main project. [Rome modules](https://github.com/rometools/rome-modules) provides support for iTunes extendsions etc.

Here is the source for the iTunes extension:
https://github.com/rometools/rome-modules/tree/master/src/main/java/com/rometools/modules/itunes